# Wildfly-Maven-Plugin only Ear and War

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

My project structure such

```
-parent
--web
--server
----moduleA
----moduleB
----moduleС
----main
```

My parent pom.xml

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${wildfly-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname>
                    <port>${wildfly-port}</port>
                    <username>${wildfly-username}</username>
                    <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
<!--                    <filename>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</filename> ??     -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I want deploy only WAR fro mweb module and EAR from main module
But now deploy all jar etc

How I must configure my maven?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `<skip>true</skip>` configuration option you could use as well. By default have it set to `true` then in the modules you want deployed change it to `false`.

On the parent pom use the following:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${wildfly-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
        <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname>
        <port>${wildfly-port}</port>
        <username>${wildfly-username}</username>
        <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then on the in the pom's for the modules you want deployed use:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>false</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn wildfly:undeploy
mvn -pl :by.mobile.main wildfly:deploy "-P moduleA, web" -DskipTests
mvn -pl :admin.mobile.ui wildfly:deploy "-P moduleA, web" -DskipTests
```

Comment: While this may anser the question, please also add a short explanation what these commands do and how they help to solve the initial problem.